# How to deal with invalid utf8 in fileinput?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I have basically the following code:

```
def main():
    for filename in fileinput.input():
        filename = filename.strip()
        process_file(filename)
```

The script takes a newline-separated list of file names as its input. However, some of the file names contain invalid utf8, which causes `fileinput.input()` to implode. I've read about the `surrogateescape` error handler, which I think is what I want, but I don't know how to set the error handler for fileinput.

In short: how do I get `fileinput` to deal with invalid Unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filenames on POSIX may be arbitrary sequences of bytes (except `b'\0'` and `b'/'`) i.e., no character encoding can decode them in the general case (that is why [`os.fsdecode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsdecode) exists that uses `surrogateescape` error handler).

You could use a binary mode to read the filenames then either skip [undecodable filenames](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/) if the input shouldn't contain them or pass them as is (or [`os.fsdecode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsdecode)) to functions that expect filenames:

```
for filename in fileinput.input(mode='rb'):
    process_file(os.fsdecode(filename).strip())
```

Beware, there were several known Python bugs related to using a binary mode and `fileinput` e.g.:

- [fileinput should use stdin.buffer for "rb" mode](http://bugs.python.org/issue21075)
- [fileinput.FileInput.readline() always returns str object at the end even if in 'rb' mode](http://bugs.python.org/issue25510)

Answer (score 1):

Following documentation please use opening hook:

```
def main():
for filename in fileinput.input(openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("utf-8")):
    filename = filename.strip()
    process_file(filename)
```